# Link doesn't work when positioning button

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a button on this site:
http://site9171756.91.webydo.com/?v=1

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="Button" style="position: absolute; left: 1000px; 
top: 100px;">dark grey</a>
```

CSS:

```
.Button {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #8bb857;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  border: solid #8bb857 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
} 

.Button:hover {
 background: #c8f098;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

If I remove the `position` code from the **html**, the link works! But of course I would like positioning my button.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with browser tools? There are huge transparent boxes all over your entire site.

Comment: no.. not sure what you mean? a have images with transparent background. is that what you mean?

Comment: No, [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EGCrD.png) is what I mean. There are these boxes over the whole site. They seem pretty useless. Is it possible for you to remove them? Because that would solve your issue as well and it would be more elegant.

Comment: hmm.. im using webydo for the site, so most of the code I cannot edit. Its a page builder system. But anyhow - It is not be a big issue. you cannot see them anyway :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<a class="Button" style="position: absolute; left: 1000px; top: 100px; z-index: 1000;" href="#">dark grey</a>
```

This will make your link and hover effects working .

I have added **z-index: 1000;** in element style.

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your stylesheet.

```
.Button {
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #8bb857;
    font-size: 20px;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: solid #8bb857 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    z-index: 10;
}
```